# Recurrsion not working in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am experiencing a strange behaviour in angular.

I am trying to iterate through a nested json object that will be returned from web service.

Following is my web service,

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value="service/admin/getPageComponents",method=RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
public ResponseData getPageComponents(@RequestParam Map<String, String> reqMap){
    Address addressp=new Address("Uni", "Tatooine");
    Student a=new Student("LukeSkywalker", "34", addressp);
    List<Student> li=new ArrayList<>();
    li.add(a);
    List<String> h=new ArrayList<>();
    h.add("name");
    h.add("age");
    h.add("add.city");
    return new ResponseData(li, h);
}
```

I want to print only name, age and city data of the student.Hence I am passing the header data separately.

In my typescript side I am mapping my list of students to tableData's columns and header's list to tableData's header.

Following is the way I am accessing this in my html,

```
<tr *ngFor="#column of tableData.columns " (click)="onRowSelect(column)" highlight>
    <td *ngFor="#key of tableData.header" >{{getText(column,key)}}</td>
</tr>
```

and in my Typescript class,

```
  getText(column,key:string){
        console.log(key+" : "+column[key]);
        if(key.indexOf(".")!=-1){

           var firstKey = key.substring(0, key.indexOf("."));
            var remainingKey=key.substring( key.indexOf(".")+1,key.length);
            let jsonObj:any=column[firstKey];
            console.log('|| '+firstKey+' || '+remainingKey+' || '+jsonObj)
            this.getText(jsonObj,remainingKey);

            // below code works as expected 
            /*
            let arr=key.split(".");
            let jsonO:any=column[arr[0]];
            return jsonO[arr[1]];*/

        }else{
            console.log("returning "+column[key]);
            return column[key];    
        }

    }
```

When I uncomment the non recurssion part and comment the recurrsion the code is working as expected and I am getting 'Uni' in my city's column.

However when i use the recurssion part, I am able to see the data in console.log but not on the page.The column is blank.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: In the recursion part, the `this.getText()` response does not get saved or returned or assigned.. what are you trying to do?

Comment: It was really a silly mistake. I missed the return statement.Thanks @PierreDuc

Comment: Ah yes, i just added it as an answer... but.. you figured it out yourself :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add a `return` in the recursion call:

```
getText(column,key:string){
    if(key.indexOf(".")!=-1){
        ...
        return this.getText(jsonObj,remainingKey); // Right here
    } else {
        return column[key];    
    }
}
```